# Permission denial: Can't access the SurfaceFlinger

Tags: android

I included the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER"/>
```

But still it gives the error.

Somebody help me, how to access the `SurfaceFlinger`.

Answer (score 1):

Allows an application to use SurfaceFlinger's low level features by adding **ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER** to manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

please post logs. Also what are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is an easier way to do it.

Also this:

> Applications signed with same system keys by which an phone resource
>   lib is signed only can access the surface flinger.

Answer (score 1):

The **SurfaceFlinger** can be access only by a system process or applications running under **shell** UID.